# Apache HttpClient: how to get redirect locations when using Fluent API?

Tags: java, redirect, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, fluent

I am using **Apache HttpClient 4.5's Fluent API**, the following way:

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
Executor executor = Executor.newInstance(client);
Response resp = executor.execute(Request.Get(url));
```

Unfortunately, I can't find a proper way of getting redirect locations (the **RedirectLocation** class).
They are normally stored in a **HttpContext** object; but when using the Fluent API, its instance is created locally in **Executor.execute(...)** and never exposed:

```
public Response execute(final Request request) {
    final HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
    /* ... */
    return new Response(request.internalExecute(this.httpclient, localContext));
}
```

I've tried to override **Executor.execute(...)** method by creating a decorator/proxy class; by creating a child class; even by copy-pasting its source into my own package.
None of these solutions were feasible (for one, **Executor** invokes package-local methods of other classes).

The only workaround I've managed to find so far was to implement my own **RedirectStrategy** and pass it to **HttpClient**:

```
public class MyRedirectStrategy extends DefaultRedirectStrategy {

    private HttpContext context;

    public RedirectLocations getRedirectLocations() {
        return (RedirectLocations) context.getAttribute(REDIRECT_LOCATIONS);
    }

    @Override
    public URI getLocationURI(final HttpRequest request, final HttpResponse response, final HttpContext context)  {
        this.context = context;  // to keep the HttpContext!
        return super.getLocationURI(request, response, context);
    }
}

/* ... */

RedirectStrategy stra = new MyRedirectStrategy();
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(stra).build();
Executor executor = Executor.newInstance(client);
Response resp = executor.execute(Request.Get(url));
for (final String redirectedUri : stra.getRedirectLocations()) {
    /* process redirectedUri's */
}
```

However, I don't think it is a proper solution. To my knowledge, **RedirectStrategies** were intended to be immutable, stateless classes, as they are passed to the **HttpClient**, which can be shared by multiple threads/connections.
In other words: logically, the **HttpContext** is not a property of a **RedirectStrategy**.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. HC fluent API hides HttpContext instance way from the consumer. Consider using HttpClient APIs directly.

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer. Can I at least get the final URL I was redirected to?